# OrientDb query execution time

Tags: c#, nosql, orientdb

I would like get query execution time in response. I'm using OrientDB 3.0 with official driver https://github.com/orientechnologies/OrientDB-NET.binary for .NET.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`c#` together with `.net core` is not supported, they stopped.
When I studied the project, I was happy. When I looked for support and saw all the issues, wrong links, scattered groups... I decided to go for neo4j.
I think `OrientDb` is good, but the documentation and links sucks.
I downloaded https://github.com/orientechnologies/OrientDB.Net and it works except I had to change something. I could connect but if you look at:
`throw new NotImplementedException();` then my pants went off.

```
In OrientDBBinaryConnectionStream replace 
            if (ConnectionMetaData.ProtocolVersion < 27)
                ConnectionMetaData.UseTokenBasedSession = false;

with

ConnectionMetaData.UseTokenBasedSession = true
Success with this unfinished business and keep me informed
```

Comment: `c#` and` .net core` are still verry much supported and I would check my facts if I were you